# 0xAPI is failing to return best price for a token pair versus Sushiswap

Tags: uniswap, 0x, sushiswap

We are using the 0xAPI to search price quotes on different exchanges for one of our native index tokens at Piedao (PLAY - [0x33e18a092a93ff21aD04746c7Da12e35D34DC7C4](https://etherscan.io/token/0x33e18a092a93ff21aD04746c7Da12e35D34DC7C4)) vs. ETH.

The current quote for 1 ETH from the 0xAPI is just under 1000 PLAY, whereas the same pair on Sushiswap is nearly 1,500 PLAY for 1 ETH. We saw the same issue on Matcha versus our website.

When investigating, we noticed that the sources from the quote appear to resolve on the following:

```json
{
    "proportion": "1",
    "intermediateToken": "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f",
    "hops": [
        "Uniswap_V3",
        "SushiSwap"
    ],
    "name": "MultiHop"
}
```

Namely, the price feed is coming from a multiple hop through Uniswap and Sushiswap, instead of fetching from Sushi directly.

Comparing with Matcha suggests to me that this is unlikely to be an implementation issue on our side, but we are happy to be proven wrong. I was wondering if someone could advise whether my understanding is correct about the above "multiple hops" issue and what steps we could take to correct? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Matcha is surfacing an [RFQ order](https://docs.0x.org/market-makers/docs/introduction), these orders are only surfaced if to integrators with a key. The 0x API quote is giving you the best option if RFQ weren't an option.

Comment: Same price across Matcha and the API - both are showing the 'worse' price. My question is why are both API and Matcha fetching the incorrect price?